# Microsoft SQL Server 2008 - Error 1206 - The Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) has cancelled the distributed transaction

Tags: sql-server-2008, vb6, adodb, pivotal-crm

I'm running a Pivotal application (5.9) and have a server process which always crashes (MS SQL error 1206).

1. I have a Pivotal "active form" with an update button, which, when clicked, calls a server process (VB 6 custom DLL)
2. This custom DLL :

   1. retrieves the list of all users who can use the Pivotal application ("users" standard table) by using the Pivotal API, and then creates its own connection to another database using a connection string)
   2. For each users, it constructs and run the a query :
   3. strSql = select SUM(stoResourceSize) totalResourceSize from " & dbName &
      ".dbo.Resource Where StorageID = 3 and XptDestinationAddress like "
      strSql = strSql & "'%" & userName & "%'"

The connection string used to run the query is the following :

```
strConnect = "Driver={SQL Server};" & _
    "Server=" & SatteliteName & ";" & _
    "UID=" & SyncStreamDBName & ";" & _
    "Trusted_Connection=Yes"
```

It works fine but the query crashes after about 80 users processed, with error 1206 and SQLState = 37000

I can reproduce that problem every single time. At a given time, this query will crash.

I have added a lot of trace and the last query works fine if I run it on the server "by hand".
It doesn't crash on the same user every time, it looks like it is random. Besides, in the application there exists another server procedure which can run the same query but only for one user. That one will run fine and never crash.
I have also tried to enabled ODBC trace but it wouldn't give me any useful information.

I'm pretty confidnet it is a connection or configuration problem but I don't know what.
This problem is reproducible both in developpment and testing environnments.

edit: actually it seems that my server process can crash at various points, not necessarily when executing that request.
It seems to crash when I open ADODB recordsets (of course, before touching any recordset, I verify that both EOF and BOF are false, and they are).

Comment: Does the original post lack information ?
Please tell me if isn't accurate enough, so that I can add more detail or organize it better.
Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: If I remember correctly there is a setting in MSDTC for transactional timeout with a default value of 60 seconds. Is the transaction live for more than 60 seconds?